# Best way to play sound on a timed interval?

Tags: android, audio, timer

I have an Android app which needs to play a sound resource on a timed interval, say every 120 seconds.

I know how to access the sound resources and play them, however it's time timer part I'm not sure of. What's the best approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up ditching the `Timer` approach and used a `Handler` instead after stumbling upon an example at [android-labs](http://code.google.com/p/android-labs/).

So, instead of spawning the `Timer` and `TimerTask` in my Activity's `onCreate`, I declared this private `Handler` with in-line `Runnable`:

```
private Handler _playRandomSoundHandler = new Handler();
private Runnable _playRandomSoundTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        SoundManager.playRandom();
        _playRandomSoundHandler.postDelayed(_playRandomSoundTask, Prefs.getDelayInMilliseconds(getApplicationContext()));
    }
};
```

Also, I had to add code to my Activity's `onResume` and `onPause`:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    _playRandomSoundHandler.postDelayed(_playRandomSoundTask, Prefs.getDelayInMilliseconds(this));
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    _playRandomSoundHandler.removeCallbacks(_playRandomSoundTask);
    SoundManager.stop();
}
```

This approach seems to work great.